# Is there a performance gain to use web-sys instead of plain old JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I used `wasm-bindgen` to write a very basic JS/Wasm webapp in which a grayscale transformation (written in Rust) is applied to an image uploaded by the user of the webapp through an `<input type="file">` and displayed in a `<canvas>`.

Doing so, I had to load the image in the WebAssembly memory space, apply the transformation on each pixel then return the result in the memory space for the JS to take care of the display:

```js
import { memory} from "img-grayscale-wasm/img_grayscale_wasm_bg";
import {MyImage} from "img-grayscale-wasm"

//...

async function processImg(file, width, height){
  const canvas = document.getElementById("pixel-grayscale");

  var resp = await fetch(file.name)
  var bytes = await resp.arrayBuffer()

  const myImage = MyImage.new();
  const ptr = myImage.alloc(bytes.byteLength); 

  // Copy to memory space
  const imgArray = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, ptr, bytes.byteLength);    
  imgArray.set(new Uint8Array(bytes));

  // transform img
  myImage.read_img(ptr, bytes.byteLength) 
  const grayScalePtr = myImage.to_grayscale(width, height)

  // read from memory space
  const arr = new Uint8ClampedArray(memory.buffer, grayScalePtr, width * height * 4);
  let imageData = new ImageData(arr, width);

  getContextFromCanvas(canvas, width, height).putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

I think I can avoid the whole process of copying stuff back and forth to the memory space if I use the web's API binding defined in the `web-sys` crate, from `fetch`ing the file to the display of the grayscaled picture.

This is where I get confused: performance-wise, is there a gain in using `web-sys` and its web's API bindings instead of doing it all in JavaScript? Well, I suppose there is, but where is it?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you're marshalling the data back and forth using browser methods at the moment to bask in `web-sys`'s glory. I have some good news and some bad news for you.

The good news is that if your code is laid out the way you've said it is (and this is where a snippet would've come in very handy), you'll gain on one memory copy going each way.

Right now, the process would be as follows:

```
            1              2
         ======>        =====>       \
Browser         WebWorker      Rust   ||
         <======        <=====      <=/
            4              3
```

(Quality ASCII art, I know)

1 is a user input of some sort. 2->3 is a `fetch` cycle. 4 is the marshalling back.

At best, if your code **is** indeed structured this way, you can get rid of the data copy on steps 2 and 3 by moving everything to `web-sys`. You will not get rid of the (relatively minimal) copy of data on 1, nor on 4.

Depending on the size of the image you're desaturating, and the computer you're running it on, this may or may not present a gain in performance. I have not looked into the internals of `web-sys` (this isn't typically my area of expertise - I'm an embedded systems developer), so I cannot speak about the internals of the crate itself, but I assume `fetch()` as done by the browser or done through `web-sys` to be identical in performance.

Comment: Thx for your answer. So, this would mean, for my particular case, using `web-sys`/`webassembly` would be like over-engineering something I could write completely in plain JS without knowing if it would benefit the performance. Right?

Comment: @on_pwogramè depends how much of it you already have in rust. You *could* write the entire thing in JS but image manipulation is something that benefits massively from SIMD, which is something that (I think?) is in the works right now.

Comment: *Depending on the size of the image you're desaturating, and the computer you're running it on, this may or may not present a gain in performance* — so your answer is **"maybe"**?

Comment: @Shepmaster it also depends on how much he already wrote in rust - and by the looks of it he edited his question with some code, so I can be more precise! The code and extra precision weren't there yesterday.

Comment: WebAssembly currently doesn't have SIMD instructions, it's a beta feature. I think for now it is always over-engineering (I mean it introduces overhead) and there is no actual benefits other than you use the same Rust, if your main purpose is DOM manipulation.